# Globalization broken in Cordova 3.X?

Tags: ios, cordova

This is quite frustrating... I created a new project with Cordova 3.3 and added the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization
```

The command successfully updated my config.xml file with:

```
<feature name="Globalization">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
</feature>
```

But when I run the app in the simulator or on an iPhone, globalization methods fail. A quick check in the console for `navigator.globalization` returns `undefined`.

I can run the same project in 2.9, and it works fine. Did I make a mistake somewhere or or is this a bug?

EDIT: I checked the version, it is the latest one. v 0.2.5 (Jan 02, 2014)

Comment: are you able to check the version of the globalization plugin?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I don't see anything in the .h or .m files. Is there some CLI trick to getting that? Didn't see anything in the docs.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon just to make sure, just got the latest one from the repo. v 0.2.5 (Jan 02, 2014). Problem still persists.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, I would submit an issue at the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
cordova prepare ios
```

Other trouble shooting tips for plugins not working on iOS

- make sure the source files of the plugin .m files are included in the target membership
- make sure dependent frameworks are included in the project

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with Cordova 3.5 & 4.0 and globalization plugin 0.3.2.
Not sure what's causing it but sometimes the plugin doesn't seem to get installed properly. In those cases the plugin source files are missing from the platforms directory and the following command returns no output:

```
find platforms -name CDVGlobalization*
```

Reinstalling the ios platform + plugins has solved the problem in my case.

Comment: I had asked this question right around the time Cordova started requiring `cordova prepare` and `cordova build` but I added a couple other potential issues in my answer in case that helps anyone.